# "Emerge from" meaning + construction

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> 1- A: Turn it off.
>
> B: No.
>
> A: Do it now. That's a direct order.
>
> B: Well, you don't want to start a battle of the wills with me because
>   you will ***emerge from that battle a broken man***.

This dialogue is from an american sitcom. What does the marked phrase mean? I think it means after that battle you will be a broken man. But I can't understand the construction of the sentence.

---

I have researched "emerge from" on internet. I have found more interesting sentences. Still don't get the constructions though.

> 2- She ***emerged from the sea, blue with cold***.
>
> 3- She ***emerged from the bedroom, a vision in cream silk***.

Comment: It should be ***a*** *direct order*.

Answer (score 2):

My initial answer would be "come out of" as in:

> you will **come out of that battle a broken man**

This agrees with the [dictionary definition #5](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/emerge) to rise, as from an ... unfortunate state ...

Comment: Thank you but I still don't get the construction. Leaving that noun phrase- a broken man- at the end of the sentence as is seems awkward to me. I would use a preposition before that phrase as in: "You will emerge from that battle ***as*** a broken man." + I even would use a preposition in your sentence: "You will come out of that battle ***as*** a broken man"

Comment: To "emerge from <something> a broken man" is a not too uncommon phrase. You can add the preposition, but to my ear "as a broken man" suggest you are like a broken man. Leaving the preposition off means you ARE a broken man. Does that make sense? I don't have a reference beyond native (mostly American) English speaker.

Comment: Thank you. Should I use a comma here like the other two example? -"Well, you don't want to start a battle of the wills with me because you will emerge from that battle, a broken man."